# On Huawei mate20 pro phone, the real camera intrinsic parameters cannot be obtained through the ARCamera#getCameraImageIntrinsics method of AREngine

Tags: android

On Huawei mate20 pro phone, the real camera intrinsic parameters cannot be obtained through the ARCamera#getCameraImageIntrinsics method of AREngine.

On Huawei mate20 pro phone, the real camera intrinsic parameters can be obtained through the ARCamera#getCameraImageIntrinsics method of AREngine.